# How to bind events to components on a modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, event-binding

I am using jQuery's [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open) for opening a dialog containing a form. What I cannot solve is how to bind events to components that is added to my modal dialog. In this case, I want to bind click or change to a checkbox that has been positioned in the dialog. There doesn't seem to be any success-method that is triggered when the dialog has been loaded. This is how I do it:

This I do in the beginning of my javascript, in the beginning of the ready-function:

```
$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "explode",
    minWidth: 400,
    modal: true
 });
```

A bit later I do this when clicking a button:

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog( "option", "title", lang.localized_text.ADD_AGENT);
$('#dialog-modal').live('dialogopen', function(msg){
        alert("Opens");
        $("#select_all").live('click', function(msg){
               alert("clicked");  
        });

 });
$.get("https://" + hostname +  "/modules/core/useradmin/adminactivities/admin_add_agent.php",function(e){
     var obj = $.parseJSON(e);
     $("#dialog-modal").html(obj.html);
     $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
     addAddAgentValidation();
}
});
```

One can clearly see that alert("Opens") is presented before the dialog is opened. Hence, dialogopen is triggered before the dialog has finished loading. But the validation handler (calls the validate function which binds the validation checks) works.

alert("clicked");  is never triggered.

How can I bind any event to a component on the modal dialog? Is there any callback function when the dialog has been created.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using live is deprecated in 1.7. Also binding it on open means if it is opened more than once, you will keep adding events to the elements every time.

Comment: You should use jQuery UI dialog event : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open Plus, $.live() is deprecated I think.

Comment: live is deprecated but it still works...

Comment: [I can't seem to recreate this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/hbaA8/1/) --and *deprecated != nonfunctional* @Shikiryu - He *is* using the event. Did you even see his code? `$('#dialog-modal').live('dialogopen'` *is what is suggested to bind with*. He just used `.live()` instead of `.bind()` which works as intended, anyway.

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.7.2. @Shik, that's the link I included in my post. Checking out your jsfiddle now. There is a difference in how to set the content compared to how I do it, can that make a difference?

Comment: I think it must be related to how I add my html. Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbaA8/2/), what I changed is how the HTML is added to the dialog so it is similar to my code. I guess this is what I need to sort out.

Comment: Thanks all, I think it was some kind of naming conflict in the end. Sorry about that. Voting to delete this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your select will be in #dialog-modal and since #dialog-modal is present on domready (and never destroyed ?), you could use $.on()

```
$('#dialog-modal').on('click', '#select_all', function(e){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

But you could also bind the click event *when* you include #select_all into the dom.

```
$.get("https://" + hostname +  "/modules/core/useradmin/adminactivities/admin_add_agent.php",function(e){
     var obj = $.parseJSON(e);
     $("#dialog-modal").html(obj.html);
     $('#select_all').click(function(e){
         alert('clicked');
     });
     $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
     addAddAgentValidation();
}
```

Comment: Can you really add an event like that when the content has been added dynamically...?

Comment: Hm, yes it works... Guess I have to study binding to dynamic content somewhat more...

Answer (score 2):

You can bind it with the .on method, which replaced .live in a recent jQuery release.  In this case you bind it to something that you know is there when the DOM is ready (like the body).  Now you only need to bind once and it will fire every time you click on a #select_all.

```
$("body").on('click', '#select_all', function () {
    alert("clicked");  
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks, but not working. Check my last comment in under my question. This may be the solution but I think I need to solve something else first.